# Symlinked PHP script's working directory

Tags: php, symlink, working-directory

I have a folder `project2` with some PHP files, extended with some generic files I added as symlinks to another folder `project`. For example:

```
project/index.php 
project/config.php 
project/templates/...
...

project2/project2_functions.php
project2/config.php
project2/index.php -> ../project/index.php
project2/templates/...
...
```

However, if I browse `project2/index.php`, it seems to use `project/config.php` and deliver contents from `project/templates/` etc. It looks like PHP somewhat resolves the symbolic link even before the working directory is set, which is used for delivering the content and find the files to include. Which is then set to the wrong location. Is there any way to circumvent this behaviour?

Comment: A symlink is just a  link not an actual file. The script that is running is located in /project not in /project2 as it actually runs the file not the link. Think of a symlink like a signpost that says go here instead.

Comment: I think it is not that easy. Usually, the symlink is invisible to an application that don't care about symlinks. And it should behave so for the user (my personal opinion). So if PHP would just 'open' the given path, it would get the PHP script, and if Apache or PHP would change into the directory using the `dirname` of the given path, it would end up in project2. But for some reason, PHP actually does what you say by itself, eg. it 'cares' for symlinks in some way and resolves them before further processing, like the changing of the working directory and thus ends up at a wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you include those files:

```
$ mkdir {a,b}
$ echo 'in A' > a/file
$ echo 'in B' > b/file
$ echo '<?php echo file_get_contents(__DIR__."/file"); echo file_get_contents("./file");' > a/idx.php        
$ ln -s ../a/idx.php b/
$ cd a
$ php idx.php 
in A
in A
$ cd ../b
$ php idx.php 
in A
in B
```

Note the [remark about `__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (which is also valid for `__DIR__`):

> Since PHP 4.0.2, **FILE** always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

Comment: Well, your example turns out 'good', as the current working directory in the second example is in fact 'b'. 
But that is not what I experience in the webserver case. Here, the working directory '.' points to the folder the resolved path points at, not the directory the script is called from.

Comment: Are you sure the working directory is also the resolved path in the very _first_ / original file called, not an otherwise included / required file?